# Cannot include Neuroph library in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries

Downloaded the Neuroph 2.9 library to include in my Java project. The library is linked into the project like so: [image: library linking]

But using any classes in the library results in the error: [image: library error]

Full admission: I am a noob with linking libraries in Java, and Google doesn't seem to have anything useful. Apparently I need to dive into the "Classpath" or some .xml config file, does anyone with more Java experience know where to start (do they recognise the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory error)? I don't think it's necessarily an issue with this particular library, but I've linked it in the wrong way or missed an important step.

Comment: Solved by adding neuroph-2.9\libs\slf4j-api-1.7.5 and neuroph-2.9\libs\slf4j-nop-1.7.6 to the Project Libraries. Adding all of the jars in that folder results in the error "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings." so don't do that.

Comment: If you solved it, answer below so that future users may benefit from this.

Comment: Done. I need to wait a day to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding neuroph-2.9\libs\slf4j-api-1.7.5 and neuroph-2.9\libs\slf4j-nop-1.7.6 to the Project Libraries.

Do not link all of the jars inside that folder. This results in the error "SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings."